# Appcelerator Titanium Animation

Tags: javascript, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working with titanium expand and collapse for Android.I have created a tablerow with a Label and image.When i click on the image then make bottom view visibility true and set height for tablerow.Then applied animation for the expand view

```
    for (var i = 0; i < sectionItems.length; i++) {


              tblCell[i] = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  id: i,

                  layout:"horizontal",
                  rowId:i
              });
            topView[i]=Ti.UI.createView({

                  height: 50,
                  backgroundColor: 'white',
                  id: i,
                 rowId:i,
                  layout:"horizontal",
                  width:"100%",

              });




              lbltitle[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                  text: sectionItems[i],
                  id:i,
                  color:'#000',
                  font: {
                      fontSize: '16dp',
                      fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro',
                      fontWeight: 'bold'
                  },
                 left: "1%",
                 width:'80%',
                 rowId:i,
                  //right: '10',
                  textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,

              });
                lblDescription[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({
                 // text: sectionItems[i].description,
                  id: i,
                  text:"Test Answer",
                  color:'#000',
                  font: {
                      fontSize: '14dp',
                      fontFamily: 'Myriad Pro',
                  },
                  backgroundColor:'green',
                  rowId:i,
                  left: "10%",
                  right:"10%",
                  top:"10dp",
                  width:'80%',
                  height:"25%",
                 textAlign: Titanium.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,

              });
              addPic[i] = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image:"/images/carat_down.png",

               rowId:i,
                id: i,

                right:"1%",

                height:'9dp',
                width:"16dp"

              });
                expandView[i]=Ti.UI.createView({
                width:"100%",
                left:'0dp',
                height:"0dp",
                backgroundColor:'red',
                 id: i,
                rowId:i,
                visible:false,
                 layout:"vertical"

              });








              topView[i].add(lbltitle[i]);
              topView[i].add(addPic[i]);
              expandView[i].add(lblDescription[i]);
              tblCell[i].add(expandView[i]);

               tblCell[i].add(topView[i]);
                addPic[i].addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {

                toggleExpand(e);
             });

function toggleExpand(e){



             if(expandView[e.source.rowId].visible==true){

             expandView[e.source.rowId].visible=false;

                tblCell[e.source.rowId].height=tblCell[e.source.rowId].height-(topView[e.source.rowId].height*3);
             expandView[e.source.rowId].animate({
                height:"0dp",duration:250}); 


           }else{
            for (var i = 0; i < tblsectionItems.length; i++) {
                if(expandView[i].visible==true){
                    expandView[i].visible=false;
                    tblCell[i].height=tblCell[i].height-(topView[i].height*3);
                    expandView[i].animate({
                    height:"0dp",duration:250});
                }}

              expandView[e.source.rowId].visible=true;

              expandView[e.source.rowId].animate({
                height:"auto",duration:250});//"auto"
              tblCell[e.source.rowId].height=tblCell[e.source.rowId].height+(topView[e.source.rowId].height*3);

           }
}
```

But when the row expand then i can't see my previous elements of tblcell.I can't find the reason.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the logic you are using to add elements in the row.
First do not use separate arrays to add each elements instead use row variable to attach elements like below..

```
var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({});
row.topView = Ti.UI.createView({});
row.expandView = Ti.UI.createView({}); like that..
```

then use only 2 objects for expanView or whatever view you want to show/hide in toggleExpand function.. like

```
if(previousView.visible == true)
{
...
}
else{
...
}
previousView = e.row.expandView;
```